# NuSOAP to PHP SOAP

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

Currently trying to update some legacy code to use PHP SOAP instead of the old NuSOAP library. The issue I'm having is that the current code has the following:

```
$parameters = array(
                'request' => array(
                    'UserCredentials' => array(
                        'Username' => $username,
                        'Password' => $password,
                        'AgentID' => $ResellerID,
                    ),
                    'UserConsent' => 'Yes',
                    'ServiceType' => 'MPF',
                )
            );

$parameters['request']['RequestDetails'] = new soapval('RequestDetails', 'TelephonePostcodeRequest', array('TelephoneNumber' => $phone_number, 'Postcode' => $post_code), false, "tns", false);
```

The problem is that soapval needs to be replaced with what I assume SoapVar() ? I've attempted the following

```
$parameters['request']['RequestDetails'] = new SoapVar(array('TelephoneNumber' => $phone_number, 'Postcode' => $post_code), XSD_STRING, 'TelephonePostcodeRequest');
```

with no luck. How can I get a similar object to pass through to the SOAP request?